# How do I replace backspace characters (\b) using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to delete a fixed number of some backspace characters ocurrences ( \b ) from stdin. So far I have tried this:

```
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | sed 's/\b{3}//'
```

But it doesn't work. How can I achieve this using sed or some other unix shell tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed interprets `\b` as a word boundary. I got this to work in perl like so:

```
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | perl -pe '$b="\b";s/$b//g'
```

Comment: The ASCII value will also do: `echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | perl -pe 's/\010//g'`

Comment: see my comment on the above question

Comment: the following did the work :  echo -e "1234\b\b5" | perl -pe 's/\010{2}/t/g'

Answer (score 10):

You can use the hexadecimal value for backspace:

```
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | sed 's/\x08\{3\}//'
```

You also need to escape the braces.

Comment: or you could use the -r flah for extended mode: `echo -e "1234\b\b\b\b5678" | sed -r 's/\o010{3}/a/'`

Comment: This is GNU sed only as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tr`:

```
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | tr -d '\b'
123456
```

If you want to delete three consecutive backspaces, you can use Perl:

```
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | perl -pe 's/(\010){3}//'
```

Comment: I dont want to replace all occurences of \b with empty space, only a certain number of occurences, thats why I tried to use the repeat pattern '{3}'

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

`echo "123\b\b\b5" | sed 's/[\b]\{3\}//g'`

You have to escape the `{` and `}` in the `{3}`, and also treat the `\b` special by using a character class.

```
[birryree@lilun ~]$ echo "123\b\b\b5" | sed 's/[\b]\{3\}//g'
1235
```

Comment: You are cheating here. You are replacing sequences of `\` and `b` of length 3, not sequences of 3 backspace characters.

Answer (score 2):

Note if you want to remove the characters being deleted also, have a look at [ansi2html.sh](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh) which contains processing like:

```
printf "12..\b\b34\n" | sed ':s; s#[^\x08]\x08##g; t s'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for Perl here!

```
# version 1
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | sed $'s/\b\{3\}//' | od -c

# version 2
bvar="$(printf '%b' '\b')"
echo -e "1234\b\b\b56" | sed 's/'${bvar}'\{3\}//' | od -c
```